# Convert date+time to date format

Tags: python, datetime

I have a column with datetime "2021-10-22 00:00:00" and I want to convert it to date with format "10/22/2021"

Thanks

Comment: please check https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert string to a `datetime` object with `.strptime()` method , then create new datetime string with `.strftime()` method and new pattern.

```
from datetime import datetime

date_time_str = "2021-10-22 00:00:00"
main_pattern = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
target_pattern = '%m/%d/%Y'

date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, main_pattern)
new_date_time = date_time_obj.strftime(target_pattern)

print (new_date_time)
```

```
#output:
#10/22/2021
```